# Ionic3 Push notification

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

Has anyone worked with notifications on `ionic 3` `IOS`?
to a week trying to use the `firabase push` `(FCM)` but without success, most of the tutorials are out of date ...
Does anyone know of any other way I can use
or if someone has some example project of using `FCM` in `IOS` for me to use / learn

Comment: I would take a look at this video. It's a nice step by step tutorial, you may want to change some things but it will set you on the right track. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOOjamH1bAA

Answer (score 0):

Code sample of using `cordova-plugin-fcm` in ionic 3.

```
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';



@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  constructor( private platform: Platform, private fcm: FCM ) {

  platform.ready().then(() => {
          this.initPushNotification();
        });
  }

    initPushNotification() {
        this.fcm.getToken().then(token => {
            console.log(token);
            // You can get and save push device token to your database. 
        });

        this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
            //This callback function is called when mobile received a push notification
            if (data.wasTapped) {
                // You can handle logic after taping push message in notification bar
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you. if you need more let me know.

Comment: Hello, do I need to use the pods? and to configure in xml the plugin just need to do this ->   ` <plugin name="cordova-plugin-fcm" spec="^2.1.2" />`  I just want to use it in IOS

Comment: Do you have any sample projects, so that I can study and learn ...?

Comment: don't need to add fcm plugin to config.xml manually. after running `ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm` command it will automatically update the xml. after that run `npm install --save @ionic-native/fcm` command. after that add above code in appropriate place and test sending push message using firebase console.

Comment: Hello I'm sorry to bother you, but I'm really looking forward to learning to use the push in IOS with ionic3, I did everything you said but it did not work, could you take a quick look at my project to see if something was wrong?

Comment: link of my project that is based on your information made everything correct but when I give build and send notification does not reach my smartphone ..
 link here ->>>https://www.4shared.com/zip/piwfXOxfgm/push.html?

Comment: What you have done is correct. APNS certificate is needed to see push notifications on iphone. did you get it?

Comment: Hello, take a look at these two images, one is showing that I already registered my app with the certificate and in the other and a print from my firebase console + ios emulator
img1 - >https://imgur.com/a/AQTiFdM   img2 - >https://imgur.com/oN1urDT

Comment: and another thing also after the build it stays like this, does not appear another screen is this https://imgur.com/a/aNz8rtb