# ionic push notification registration not triggered

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic3

I have an ionic project, which i want to implement a push notification, i have the following below

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    const options: PushOptions = {
         android: {
             senderID: 'XXXXX' firebase sender_id
         },
         ios: {
             alert: 'true',
             badge: true,
             sound: 'false'
         },
         windows: {}
      };

     const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);
alert('Alert 1');
 pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
     alert('Alert 2');
    if (notification.additionalData.foreground) {
      let youralert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'New Push notification',
        message: notification.message
      });
      youralert.present();
    }
  });
pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
     //do whatever you want with the registration ID
      alert('Alert 3');
  });
   alert('Alert 4');
      pushObject.on('error')
.subscribe(error =>  alert('Alert 5'););
      }
});
```

when i install on my android device, alert 1 and 4 are triggered, but alert 2, alert 3 and 5 are not, any ideas what i am doing wrong

cordova version = 8.0.0
ionic version = 3.20.0

Comment: I suggest you to use `cordova-plugin-firebase` plugin. When I was developing push notification I had to face many issues with this and after that I used `cordova-plugin-firebase` plugin.

Comment: when  i use this i keep getting "Unfortunately myapp has stopped". Kindly advice

Comment: What you mean by "this" ? is it `cordova-plugin-firebase` ?

Comment: Sudarshana Dayananda yes cordova-plugin-firebase

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50770869/ionic3-push-notification/50771102#50771102